# error with the replace function in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a problem with the replace function in mysql for example

```
set @str = "Category, CategoryName, CategoryID";
SELECT REPLACE (@str, "Category", "125");
```

I would replace only the first word "Category"
and here's the result:

```
125,125Name, 125ID
```

how to fix the problem

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you realy want to use MySQL REPLACE function, the only option I see is this:

```
set @str = "Category, CategoryName, CategoryID";
SELECT REPLACE (@str, "Category,", "125,");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to replace only the first characters (*if you define the first characters has to be equal to the string "Category"*) you can give a try:

```
SELECT 
  fieldname,
  REPLACE(fieldname, 'Category', '125'),
  LEFT(fieldname, 8),
  RIGHT(fieldname, (LENGTH(fieldname)-8)),
  CONCAT('125', RIGHT(fieldname, (LENGTH(fieldname)-8)))
FROM tablename
WHERE LOWER(LEFT(fieldname, 8)) = 'category';
```

Your result look like this:

```
CategoryNameCategorySomethingElse | 125Name125SomethingElse | 
Category | NameCategorySomethingElse | 125NameCategorySomethingElse
```

Now, you can prepare your update statement:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET fieldname = CONCAT('123', RIGHT(fieldname, (LENGTH(fieldname)-8))) 
WHERE LOWER(LEFT(fieldname, 8)) = 'category';
```